# Telegram bot livecheck or how to get bot's chat id

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Can I use telegram api for the bot live-check automation? There are dozens of bots created by a third-party service so I cannot modify their source code, but I've their names and tokens.

I thought I can create a bot who will send messages to others bots, but I can't find any info of how to obtain bot chat id.

So the question is how to obtain bot chat id to write a message to him from another bot. Or how to health check telegram bots.

Comment: you want to obtain bot's `chat_id` by its `@name`?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov it'll be nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram bots do not receive updates from other bots, otherwise this could lead to infinite looping.

[Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)